# Passing a variable by reference to a recurring function

Tags: c++, recursion, pass-by-reference, static-variables

Is an argument to a function which is a reference to variable treated `static` in recursive function? Below is a function for finding kth smallest root in a BST.

```
int findNode(TreeNode* root, int &k) {
    if(root == NULL)
        return -1;
    // We do an inorder traversal here.
    int k1 = findNode(root->left, k);
    if(k == 0) return k1; // left subtree has k or more elements.
    k--;
    if(k == 0) return root->val; // root is the kth element.
    return findNode(root->right, k); // answer lies in the right node.
}

int kthsmallest(TreeNode* root, int k) {
    return findNode(root, k);  // Call another function to pass k by reference.
}
```

The function `kthsmallest` returns the kth smallest node's value.

Node definition:

```
struct TreeNode {
    int val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;
}
```

My question is why is `k` passed by reference.

Comment: Because it is modified in the function? And used *after* the recursive call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It is not being used in the function which called it as you can see.

Comment: No, but the recursive call may modify it, and then it is used inside the `findNode` function. And the `findNode` could be called from other places as well maybe? I suggest you step through the code in a debugger, stepping into the recursive calls, to see what really happens.

Comment: `k--` modifies `k`. The reference ensures that all `k`s are the same `k`.

Comment: @user4581301 Thats what I was asking. So, does passing k by reference makes it behave like a static variable? Otherwise for every recursive call it will have a new copy with values from the stack. But here it might be the case where previous values in the stack are overwritten due to passing by reference. Am I right?

Comment: No. [Static implies a different storage class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Think of this as many variables that are all aliases to one root variable that happens to be temporary but scoped wide enough that it will outlive the recursion. This may be done with something akin to pointers, but maybe not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `k` is relevant to the overall algorithm, not the individual call to `findNode`. It is like a countdown timer; the algorithm terminates when `k` reaches 0. All the recursive calls contribute to the same countdown.

Passing a reference to a variable in a calling scope solves a similar problem as `static`, but it's generally considered a superior technique in software engineering. Globals (e.g. `static`) limit a program's scalability.

The moral of the story is not to use names like `k`. Call it something like `remaining_nodes`.